# VBA: Export Word Doc to PDF with a different file name

Tags: vba, ms-word

Currently I am using the code below which saves the word doc into a PDF with its default file name. I want to change it such that I can modify the PDF file name. Appreciate it!

Code:

```
Sub Silent_save_to_PDF()
'
' Silent Save_to_PDF Macro
'
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf") , _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, to change the filename, change "ActiveDocument.FullName" for any string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the file name explicitly.

```
Sub Silent_save_to_PDF()

    Dim extra_text As String
    Dim file_name As String

    extra_text = "123"
    file_name = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & Left(ActiveDocument.Name, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.Name, ".") - 1) & extra_text & ".pdf"

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=file_name, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
    wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! this works. Is there any way I can retain the original name of the document and add additional text after? For example, I want to add '123' after the original filename for every document.

Comment: See revision for a more generic way to accomplish what you're looking for.